# Adding Library to my sketchbook

Tags: arduino-uno, rfid

Hey so basically I have my Arduino uno r3 setup with my RFID-RC522. I am looking to add this library to so I can use the examples alongside the ones I already have.
https://github.com/BoolLi/RC522_RFID_NFC_Utilities

I haven't been able to add them correctly and hope someone can help me out doing this. I currently have these ones already added and working correctly:
https://github.com/miguelbalboa/rfid

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Libraries

Comment: @Majenko I am not able to do these. I have been fiddling around with them through various ones of these methods. For example the add library from zip throws this error:Arduino: 1.8.0 (Linux), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Uno"

Specified folder/zip file does not contain a valid library

Comment: Well, it doesn't help that the author of that library doesn't know the first thing about formatting a library...

Comment: Have a look at a good library and see what is wrong with this one.  Usually its the structure or the textfile, or the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download https://github.com/BoolLi/RC522_RFID_NFC_Utilities/archive/master.zip
2. Copy the folder `RC522_RFID_Utilities` from the downloaded file to {sketchbook folder}/libraries. You can find the location of your sketchbook folder in the Arduino IDE at **File > Preferences > Sketchbook location**.
3. If you're using Arduino IDE 1.6.5-r5 or older restart the Arduino IDE. If using a newer version no restart is necessary.

The other three folders in the downloaded file are example sketches, not libraries. After installing the RC522_RFID_NFC_Utilities library following the instructions above you will be able to use them. You can store those folders anywhere you like but you should not put them directly under the libraries folder as this will cause warning messages about invalid libraries on every compilation. If you do want to bundle them with the RC522_RFID_NFC_Utilities library, as is customary, you can do this:

1. Create a folder named `examples` in {sketchbook folder}/libraries/RC522_RFID_NFC_Utilities
2. Copy the example sketch folders (NDEFFormattingExample, etc) from the downloaded file to the `examples` folder you created.
3. Restart the Arduino IDE if it's running.

The example sketches will now be accessible via **File > Examples > RC522_RFID_NFC_Utilities**.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. My issue was I never knew to take the Utilities folder and put it into the library and then have the examples within it. They are showing up fine for me now. Now just to try and sort the compiling error :)